# How to bypass all Excel message boxes with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that loops through sheets of data and creates charts based on each set of data.  That works great.  But when I added a line to the code to add a black border to each chart (j is the index used to loop through and identify the appropriate chart):

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("MyChart" & j).Line
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
End With
```

Excel displays the following message box for each chart being created when I run the code:

"Complex formatting that is applied to the selected chart may take a while to display.  Do you want to continue using the formatting?
Yes/No"

The code works fine if I just keep clicking "Yes" for each chart it's creating until the code is finished, but I don't want Excel to ask this at all, I want it to just go ahead with the formatting.

Everywhere I've looked in my research for how to do this says to set:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

But this isn't working.  Excel still displays the Yes/No box every time. Are there other ways to suppress messages/alerts in Excel?  Why isn't the above line of code working?

Comment: Are you also setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?

Comment: Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Comment: Could we see the code you're using that's triggering that warning?

Comment: I edited my question to add the code I'm using that is triggering the warning.  Yes, Application.ScreenUpdating = False.

Comment: I have a hard time believing `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` isn't turning that message off. Are you sure you have it in the right point in your code?